# In ASP.Net, how can I open a link in a new window?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button which redirects the user to another page. Instead, I would like this button to open a new window that points to this location. Can anyone please help me to do this?

**aspx:**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="img_url"
                 CommandName='<%#Eval("url") %>'
                 OnClick="img_url_Click"
                 runat="server"
                 ImageUrl="~/images/products_details.png"
                 />
```

**cs:**

```
protected void img_url_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton img = sender as ImageButton;
    Response.Redirect(img.CommandName.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a standard HTML anchor instead, containing the image.

```
<a href='<%# Eval("url") %>' target="_blank">
   <asp:Image RunAt="server"
              ID="detailsImage" 
              ImageUrl="~/images/products_details.png" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add OnClientClick="formname.target='_blank'" to you ASP.net Controller.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="img_url"
                 CommandName='<%#Eval("url") %>'
                 OnClick="img_url_Click"
                 runat="server"
                 ImageUrl="~/images/products_details.png"
                 OnClientClick="formname.target='_blank'"
                 />
```

Your codebehind redirect will occur on your new page.

Comment: Nice trick, just keep in mind that from then on all other submit buttons on the previous window will open in a new window.

Comment: :) thanks, that's true, but you can take it a step further by resetting the target once clicked. or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onclick you could use [onclientclick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclientclick.aspx) and pass the javascript [window.open](http://wap.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

something like:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="img_url"
                 CommandName='<%#Eval("url") %>'
                 OnClientClick="window.open('<%#Eval("url") %>')"
                 runat="server"
                 ImageUrl="~/images/products_details.png"
                 />
```